# app-engine: Request Data

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web, webapp2

in my webapp2.RequestHandler method:

I want to find out which uri the requester want to get.
for example, if the user wants to get "http://www.mysite.com/products/table"
I want to get into a variable the value "table" (in this case)

when I print "self.request" I see all the values of RequestHandler class
but I didn't managed to find out what is the right attribute in my case.

I'm sure the question is an easy-one for you, but I'm just a starter in python and app-engine framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked into how URLs should be handled, and wildcard URLs.  Try this:

```
class ProductsHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, resource):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        table = self.request.url
        self.response.out.write(table)
        self.response.out.write("\n")
        self.response.out.write(resource)

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
        ('/products/(.*)', ProductsHandler)
        ],
        debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)
```

When I go to the URL `http://localhost:8080/products/table`, I get this result:

> http://localhost:8080/products/table
>   table

The `resource` parameter of the `get` function is passed in automatically by the [`WSGIApplication`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/wsgiapplicationclass.html) `url_mapping`, because it is mapped to:

```
('/products/(.*)', ProductsHandler)
```

The `(.*)` is a wildcard, and gets passed in as a method parameter.

You could name the parameter in the `get` method anything you want instead of `resource`, such as `table`.  It wouldn't make a lot of sense though, because if you pass in a url like `http://localhost:8080/products/fish`, it would no longer contain the word "table".

---

#### Earlier attempt (before edits):

Try something like this:

```
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        table = self.request.url
        self.response.out.write(table)
```

For my test, I went to `http://localhost:8080/`, and it printed out:

> http://localhost:8080/

See [the docs for the `Request` class here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_url).